# text field greater than or equal to having weird effects in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, textfield

I have a trigger set like below

```
var thiseffect:Boolean = false;

if (thistx.text >="6" && thistx.text <="12")
{ thiseffect = true; }
```

and the trigger will not activate in this case however if I change the 12 value in this trigger to a value below 10, OR if I change the 6 value to something greater than 10 it will trigger with no problem

Im not really sure why that is, has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isnt exactly an answer but rather a solution

I have converted my text input into a number variable and the trigger activates with no problem now

```
var thiseffect:Boolean = false;
var mynum:Number = Number(thistx.text);

if (mynum>=6 && mynum<=12)
{ thiseffect = true; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following operators to compare strings: <, <=, !=, ==, =>, and >.

But You should note: When using these operators with strings, ActionScript considers the character code value of each character in the string, comparing characters from left to right.

So in your example it compares left to right character by character not by the actual integer value.

```
trace("12" <= "6") ;//evaluates true
trace("12" <= "06");//evaluates false
```

[refer to Adobe Doc files here.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7eef.html)